# Changing the alignment of dynamic labels

Tags: vb.net, dynamic, label, text-alignment

I have made a program that deals with labels' text alignment.

I have used:

```
Dim con7 As Control
For Each con7 In Me.Controls
    con7.TextAlign = 'whatever is needed
Next
```

But the problem is the `TextAlign` part. The problem that arises is that `TextAlign` is not a property of all controls. What is the best way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to assign each child control to a variable of type `Label` but, as the error message indicates, you clearly have at least one control that is not a `Label`.  There are a couple of ways you can handle that but the simplest is to use `Me.Controls.OfType(Of Label)()`, which will filter out all but `Label` controls.

Comment: I'll try that as soon as I can

Comment: The code you posted can't work for anything. If you have similar code that works then I would guess that your variable in that case is actually type `Control` rather than type `Label`.

Comment: No. It is literally the same code except for `TextAlignment`

Comment: Either it's different code or it's a different child controls. Anything else is simply not possible.

Comment: It can work if I use a property common for all controls

Comment: It could work depending on the property. Some properties are common throughout all controls.

Comment: And exactly what use is that if what you want is to set the `TextAlign` property of the `Label` controls? If you were setting a property common to all controls then there'd be no problem in the first place and you never would have posted this question, so why are you wasting your time and mine posting that irrelevant comment?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the following code:

```
Dim con7 As Control
```

`con7` is declared within the loop.

Since you only want to loop through labels use the following code:

```
For Each lbl In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Label)()

    lbl.TextAlign = ...

Next
```